# AES -192 encryption/decryption using php?

Tags: php, aes

I have done AES128 encryption/decryption in php using the AES128 script available at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3650-PHP-A-pure-PHP-AES-128-encryption-implementation.html
or http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17721.html
Now I have a key of 24 characters and data(already stored in database) is encrypted using the 24 character key. So I am supposed to decrypt this data.

I think it is AES-192 (correct me if am wrong) coz its 24 character key.
Is it possible to modify the AES128.php code available at phpclasses(link is above) so that it can be used to decrypt AES192 encrypted data.
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try modifying to code yourself if you don't know much about cryptography. Chances of getting something wrong are pretty high.

If you're free to change the AES implementation you use, why not use the PHP supplied  **mcypt** module (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php)? It supports AES-128, -192, -256-bit (under the name MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_xxx) and much, much more. Plus, as a free bonus, you can find tons of code examples for it.

Here is an example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#78531.

Comment: The php server is not hosted in my system and I cannot download the library files required for mycrypt

Comment: Hm, well, I don't find much for a non-lib based solution, appart from this (non-free) library: http://www.phpaes.com.

Comment: You probably have to load it first, everything is at the link I supplied. E.g. installation etc. here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php.

Comment: -1 RIJNDAEL_192 is **NOT** the same as AES-192. The numbers after RIJNDAEL specify the block size, while the numbers after AES specify the key size. AES always uses a 128 bit block size. RIJNDAEL_128 using a 192 bit key is AES-192. I'll convert the downvote if you fix your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use mycrypt and RIJNDAEL-192 cipher, it is the same than AES.

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Comment: It would be helpful if a sample code for mycrypt or RIJNDAEL-192 is given.. I use php version 5.2.8

Comment: -1 RIJNDAEL_192 is **NOT** the same as AES-192. The numbers after RIJNDAEL specify the block size, while the numbers after AES specify the key size. AES always uses a 128 bit block size. RIJNDAEL_128 using a 192 bit key is AES-192.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, i resolved my problem, that i posted here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124403/decryption-of-a-file-on-php-server-using-openssl-commands/18128059