# Decryption of a file on php server using openssl commands

Tags: php, c, linux, encryption, openssl

I am encrypting a file on client side and trying to decrypt it on my linux server using openssl command, its creating output file but with 0 bytes size.

The code I am using in php for decrypting file is:

`system("openssl enc -d -aes-192-ecb -in secure.cxf -out plain.xml -K 11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff0011223344556677");`

here I am using AES in ECB mode with 192 bit (24 byte) key,

where

`secure.cxf` is input file in same folder with php file

`plain.xml` is output file comes with 0 bytes

`11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff0011223344556677` is my private key of decryption

I have tried the same openssl command on different linux operationg systems, the command works fine but on server it makes empty output file. Any idea how to resolve the empty file problem? 
Is there any alternative way to do same decryption (AES, ECB mode, 192 bit key) for files on php server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you do not specify -out ?

Comment: It returns decoded file instead of writing it in output file

Comment: if it return then you can try use `>` command operator. Like `system("openssl enc -d -aes-192-ecb -in secure.cxf -K 11223344556677889900aabbccddeeff0011223344556677 > plain.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

try one of this:

a) create empty file `plain.xml` and permission to 0666 `chmod 0666 plain.xml`

or

b) set permission on parent Directory your php file. `chmod 0777 DirectoryWithMyFile`

You can do this in FTP client or SSH.

Another Way - from `phpinfo()` find tmp dir and use this dir.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have checked, permissions are not really my problem. I have edited the question too.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem for decryption by another way using php. If anybody looking for same follow this.

[AES -192 encryption/decryption using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550300/aes-192-encryption-decryption-using-php#comment-20621577)